# how to jsp dynamic modal?

Tags: jquery, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I'm setting up a jsp dynamic page that shows data from MySQL database,
every thing fine until I used a modal to display some info, but it won't it keeps showing one data.

so I tried some injection using jquery, still I get the same stuff

Here is my model:

```
<button type="button" id="btnModal" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img style="width: 25px; height: 25px" src="./Vistas/img/taxista.png"></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header mark">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>                                                 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <form class="" action="Controlador">
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="buscarFecha" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the div I'm trying to inject with jquery:

```
<div id="infoModal">
    <div class="modalHeader">                              
        <h4 class="modal-title"><%=t.getNombre()%> <%= t.getNum_licencia()%></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modalBody">
        Telefono: <%=t.getTelefono()%> <br>
        Marca de coche: <%=t.getMarcaCoche()%> <br>
        Modelo: <%=t.getModelo()%> <br>
        Matricula: <%=t.getMatricula()%> <br>
        Poblacion: <%=t.getPoblacion()%>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $header = $("#myModal .modal-header"),
                $body = $("#myModal .modal-body");
        $("#btnModal").click(function () {
            var headerContent = $("#infoModal .modalHeader").html();
            $header.html(headerContent);
            var bodyContent = $("#infoModal .modalBody").html();
            $body.html(bodyContent);
        });
    });
</script>


https://jsfiddle.net/zc4rfpwn/
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your jQuery selectors.

Here `var $header = $("#myModal .modal-header")` you are trying to select an element with the ID `myModal` and the class `.modal-header`. But you don't have an element with the id myModal.

First you need to add the id to your modal element

Then you need to select that element in your jQuery with

```
var $header = $('#myModal).find('.modal-header');
```

Comment: my bad, i didnt include it, i have mymody id

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>

thing is the selectors works perfectly, problem is that it only receives the first data, which means, its not dynamic

Comment: do i need a for each statement in jquery?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. I assume you want to load data for multiple elements. But i would advise against loading all data at page load into a div or whatever. You would have to load alot of data that might never get used. I would let my backhand serve the data at need. E.g. add an identifier for the data you need to your button, make an ajax call to your backend asking for the data you need, get a json object with the data you need and use some templating engine to load that json data into your modal

Comment: Here is the Fiddel: 

snippets are data from my database, they all works perfectly

but the modal keeps bringing out same content

https://jsfiddle.net/zc4rfpwn/

Comment: IDs are unique in html so if u happen to have multiple elements with the same ID and select that element in jQuery you always get the first. You select the #infoModal by its ID so even if you happen to have  multiple elements you will alawys get the first. But please see my comment above i would advise against loading - possibly hundreds - of divs with data that never gets used.

Comment: thank you for your reply ill have a look at my id, but i'm not familia with ajax, either jquery, id appreciate a step by step thank you!

Comment: Well the step by step is pretty much in my first comment : Change your button so that every one of your buttons has the id of the data it has to fetch in an attribute. Make an ajax call when you press that button fetching data from an endpoint using the id you added to the button's attribute to get what you want. In the success function of your ajax call, swap the modal's data with the newly fetched data and open the modal. You should be able to google how an ajayx call works and how you open a modal manually and swap data in an html element.

Comment: i only have one button, and its dynamic, its inside a for loop, for each data and i know nothing about ajax, i will really appreciate some help im lost

Comment: what do you mean by "you have 1 button and its dynamic" whats dynamic about it ? if you generate 1 button in a forr loop , you generate several buttonds dont you ?